# Delete flag record

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I used flag 6 times when I didn't knew what flagging means. They all were declined. I want to delete those from my account. How do I delete them?

Edit: By `didn't knew` I mean I didn't knew how do I check for response by moderator for a particular flag.

Comment: Out of curiosity was there some way in which the dialog that pops up when flagging isn't clear about what the function does? What  did you _think_ it meant that could have been clarified by the UI?

Comment: @Caleb yes, I am curious too.  'I used flag 6 times when I didn't knew what flagging means' seems like a dangerous philosophy, in general:)

Comment: @MartinJames: haha Its not so dangerous philosophy sir. I was badly down-voted on a question and then I was banned on ask questions. I somehow wanted to get rid of the question so I started flagging for moderator intervention to delete the question. I didn't know how to check for moderators response after flagging. So I kept on flagging the same question again and again till I got to know how to check for moderators' response for a flag raised.

Comment: Any idea on why did someone down vote my valid question?

Comment: @Caleb: Any idea why is the question being down-voted? I just clarified my doubt in a valid way on the right site. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 8):

You can't delete flags from your account flagging history, and should not do that.

Nobody except you and moderators can see your flags history, so there is no "public shame" issue. The only thing visible to everyone is the amount of *helpful* flags you raised: (and it's not clickable for anyone except you and moderators)

> [image]

Just take this as a lesson and flag properly in the future, and all will be good, no harm done.

Comment: *and it's not clickable*, well it is, for the user ....

Comment: *throwing clickable .... on @rene* ;-)

Comment: 1. But I might run into risk of being banned of flagging if anymore flags of mine are declined. So i want to delete them. 2. How could you see the information you posted as screenshot? I can't see the same of yours.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni Deleting stuff never works in your favor of being banned. That goes for posts as it goes for flags. Just flag correctly and if you don't know how or what to flag read up on that in the [help] or in the [tag:faq] posts on the topic. You can find your flags [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/352984/shridhar-r-kulkarni?tab=topactivity) at the right side of the page. or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5343790/shridhar-r-kulkarni?tab=topactivity) for your SO account.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni it does not work this way. This isn't a computer game where you can load old save point. You can't erase past mistakes. So yes, this can be used to ban you from flagging if you keep the bad behavior. As for screenshot, it's from [your own profile on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5343790/shridhar-r-kulkarni?tab=topactivity), each profile got different details, so you indeed see different numbers for my profile.

Comment: */me writes feature request for implementing save point*

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I know the screenshot has been taken from my own profile. Its just that I don't know do I check number of helpful flags raised by other users.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni go to their profile, go to the activity tab, and it's there below the impact. e.g. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene?tab=topactivity) that rene cast 966 helpful flafs here on MSE.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't delete from what I know, but you, mods and community team are the only one to see that record.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) for what is flagging.